# How to Bulk insert Hindi Text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have .text file in this way

```
केस रेयाज अन्सारी   
सय्यद शेबाज सय्यद गफ्फर
```

I want to make bulk insert

When I am inserting using bulk command

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[test_enrollment2] FROM 'C:\Test\test2.txt'
```

Table shows value like this

```
αñòαÑçαñ╕ αñ░αÑçαñ»αñ╛αñ£ αñàαñ¿αÑìαñ╕αñ╛αñ░αÑÇ
αñ╕αñ»αÑìαñ»αñª αñ╢αÑçαñ¼αñ╛αñ£ αñ╕αñ»αÑìαñ»αñª αñùαñ½αÑìαñ½αñ░
```

while making entry Using insert command

```
Insert into table (column name) values(N'केस रेयाज अन्सारी  ')
```

It shows proper please suggest

It is not possible to write insert command because I have more than 5carore value

My column type is `nvarchar(200)`

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

BULK INSERT [dbo].[test_enrollment2] FROM 'C:\Test\test2.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","') - See more at: 
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file#sthash.2ZsF5T8Q.dpuf

you don't have any delimiter in your data as from the sample data i see.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
-- Hindi

```
Insert into MultiLanguage_Will_Not_Work values (1, 'with N', N'मेरा नाम है')
```

Datatype of table coloumn is n

```
nvarchar
```